# Querying related rows based on order and column value

Tags: mysql, sas

The table below consists of logs of when an operation with a given ID started and finished, as indicated by `operation` column.

Is there a way to produce a SAS view that will have the following columns - `runID`, `type`,`sessionName` ,`startTime`,`endtime` and `durationInMinutes`? It should consist of related rows that have the same ID and the `startTime` and `endTime` are the two closest rows by time from each other.

```
id  operation   time
1   starts  13:45
2   starts  13:46
3   starts  13:50
4   starts  13:55
2   ends    14:02
1   ends    14:50
3   ends    14:51
1   starts  15:25
3   starts  15:42
2   starts  15:51
4   ends    18:02
1   ends    18:09
3   ends    18:25
2   ends    18:30
```

Comment: If you sort by ID then time does the data lineup start/end or can there be orphan starts/ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are efter somethink like this. I do a self join and start off from there. Let me know if any clarifications needed.

```
data inData;
input id  operation $10.  time time. ;
format time hhmm. ;
datalines; 
1   starts  13:45
2   starts  13:46
3   starts  13:50
4   starts  13:55
2   ends    14:02
1   ends    14:50
3   ends    14:51
1   starts  15:25
3   starts  15:42
2   starts  15:51
4   ends    18:02
1   ends    18:09
3   ends    18:25
2   ends    18:30

;

proc sql;
create view tempView as
select a.id, a.operation as Type , a.Time as StartTime,
    b.operation as Type2,  b.time as EndTime,  
    INTCK('minute',a.Time,b.Time) as durationInMinutes
from indata a inner join indata b
    on a.id=b.id
group by a.id, b.Time
having durationInMinutes > 0 and a.operation='starts' and
    b.operation='ends'
order by a.id , StartTime, durationInMinutes
;
quit;

proc sql;
create view YourView as
select *
from TempView
group by ID , StartTime 
having min(durationInMinutes)=durationInMinutes
;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks, it put me in the right direction, I'll start from there :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
SET @time='00:00'; SET @cnt=0;

SELECT @cnt:=@cnt+1 runID, `id`, start_time, end_time, TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time) duration 
FROM (
SELECT `id`, @time start_time, @time:=`time` end_time, `operation`
FROM yourTableName
ORDER BY `id`, `time`, `operation` DESC) tmp
WHERE tmp.`operation`='ends'
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just as easy or easier in base SAS.  Does require it be sorted or indexed - if it's indexed, you can skip the intermediate sorted view `have_s`.

```
data have;
input id  operation $ time :time5.;
datalines;
1   starts  13:45
2   starts  13:46
3   starts  13:50
4   starts  13:55
2   ends    14:02
1   ends    14:50
3   ends    14:51
1   starts  15:25
3   starts  15:42
2   starts  15:51
4   ends    18:02
1   ends    18:09
3   ends    18:25
2   ends    18:30
;;;;
run;
proc sql;
  create view have_s as
    select id, operation,time
    from have
    order by id, time, operation descending;
quit;
data want/view=want;
  set have_s;
  by id;
  retain startTime;
  if first.id then startTime=.;
  if operation='starts' then startTime=time;
  else if operation='ends' then do;
    endTime=time;
    durationInMinutes = intck('minute',startTime,endTime,'c') ;
    output;
  end;
run;
```